Use external DisplayPort/HDMI audio with Nouveau
Good day everyone.
My laptop has a RTX 4080 Nvidia dGPU with HDMI and DisplayPort directly connected to it. Video works perfectly, but I have no audio. I wonder if it’s fixable or just not supported with the open drivers. I use Tumbleweed, with Plasma (Wayland session).
~> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [GP01]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

If I use alsamixer or simply the KDE's settings, I can clearly see that I can either select the laptop's audio output, or my HDMI's. If I use the latter, I can change the volume (lower or higher), but actually no sound is reproduced. Happens actually on any distro. Audio works good with Windows or any other device connected to the monitor (Android, ChromeOS, Fire TV stick, Nintendo Switch).
~> sudo lspci -nnk |grep -E "3D|VGA"
[sudo] password di root:  0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics [8086:a788] (rev 04)
    
    0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation AD104M [GeForce RTX 4080 Max-Q / Mobile] [10de:27a0] (rev a1)


Not (yet) supported by nouveau for the newer chipsets.

It is instead, it's clearly there in the feature matrix.

Resolved by enabling the discrete-GPU-only mode in my laptop's BIOS.
It's also important to disable the auto-login in the OS or, otherwise, logout and login again. Otherwise, if you have a laptop with multiple ports, change port. Apparently, on Linux, both Nouveau and Nvidia treat every port differently. In any case, the Nvidia proprietary driver is the one that works better with audio.
